# Probability in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe like the one mentioned below.

How to count the probability of the occurrence of one in `Column_1` according to the `Column_2` and `Column_3` ?

`Column_1` is a result (either one or zero).

`Column_2` `Column_3` is a kind of classification.

So the first row means 1 for a person who lives in building numbers A with a car is model LM.

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
 1        A         LM
 1        B         LO    
 0        C         LP
 1        D         LM
 0        A         LK
 1        A         LM
```

If i understand correct the result could be

```
    LM    LO    LP    LK
A  .33                0
B              .167
C               0
D  .167
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index='Column_2', 
                      columns='Column_3', 
                      values='Column_1', 
                      aggfunc='sum', 
                      fill_value=0))
Column_3  LK  LM  LO  LP
Column_2                
A          0   2   0   0
B          0   0   1   0
C          0   0   0   0
D          0   1   0   0
```

Another solution with `groupby` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Column_2','Column_3'])['Column_1'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Column_3  LK  LM  LO  LP
Column_2                
A          0   2   0   0
B          0   0   1   0
C          0   0   0   0
D          0   1   0   0
```

Last you can divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) `length` of `index` - it is `length` of `df`:

```
print (df1.div(len(df.index)))
Column_3   LK        LM        LO   LP
Column_2                              
A         0.0  0.333333  0.000000  0.0
B         0.0  0.000000  0.166667  0.0
C         0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
D         0.0  0.166667  0.000000  0.0
```

Comment: To get the probability i think i have to divide the sum by the length of Column_1  not the sum of 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, why 0.33 ? What is formula?

Comment: The length of Column_1 is 6 in this case so if you divide 2/6 = 0.33